# Auto Increment Field on Insert without identity

Tags: t-sql

I want to have a filed on a table that I can increment myself based on variable in other tables so for instance I want to use the SQL

```
INSERT INTO Tab1( a, b, c )
SELECT ( x, y Z) FROM Tab2
WHERE......
```

But 'Z' is external from Tab2 and I need to increment it by another Variable for each record returned from Tab2

so the date in tab1 will end up

```
( FldaVal, fldbVal, 100 )
( FldaVal, fldbVal, 200 )
( FldaVal, fldbVal, 300 )
```

But the next time I run the insert command it may be

```
( FldaVal, fldbVal, 150 )
( FldaVal, fldbVal, 200 )
( FldaVal, fldbVal, 250 )
```

To End up with 6 Records as above

I will always have the Initial value i.e. 200 in the first instance and 150 in the second

Comment: MySql != Sql Server. Pick one product please. Also, please edit your question to include sample data and desired results. Also, rolling your own auto-increment has about 99% chance of failure, even if you really know your stuff.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. `tsql` narrows, but does not specify, the software you are using.